# How can I do tabletop manipulation with a 5DOF arm?

Tags: ros, manipulator, best-practices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, if i want to do my robotic arm to recognition an object using camera and get it
there are missing steps for me like that

1. Do i get the kinematics and inverse kinematics of my arm by Kinematic Stack ??
2. what is all benefits of making my arm simulation on gazebo and RVIZ ?
3. first write my URDF file of my arm or simulate it firstly ??
4. what the most stacks and package i will deal with in this project using arm 5 DOF and one camera ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45537/how-can-i-do-tabletop-manipulation-with-a-5dof-arm?/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-10-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. There is a package named arm_kinematics_constraint_aware under ros/fuerte/stacks/arm_navigation. it can do both forward and inverse kinematics.
2. according to my understanding, simulation is used mainly for checking. for example, i'd like to do a manipulation first in the simulation to see if it works well. if it does, then i do it with the real robot.
3. to import your robot into gazebo or rviz, you MUST create URDF first.
4. the stack [arm_navigation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation) can do most of the things for you. There all also plenty of [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials). For the preception with camera, you need other packages, e.g., [tod](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tod), [object_recognition](http://www.ros.org/wiki/object_recognition).

besides, i strongly recommend this tutorial [IROS 2011 Tutorial: Motion Planning for Real Robots](http://www.kavrakilab.org/iros2011). you can read this tutorial first to get a whole picture.

---

Originally posted by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) with karma: 741 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-11-07**:
@yangyangcv is tod supported for fuerte too? There are a lot of "diamondback"s there.

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-11-07**:
@yygyt i'm not sure. you may need to change some part of tod in fuerte